# Getting Exception while generating Axis2 Client from Eclipse: QName is null

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, webclient

I am using eclipse, Jboss and Axis2,

getting following exception while generating webServiceClient from Eclipse

```
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Element QName is null for ExceptionServiceException!
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:222)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1008)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:811)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:254)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:274)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Element QName is null for ExceptionServiceException!
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
... 62 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Element QName is null for ExceptionServiceException!
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:537)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:282)
... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Element QName is null for ExceptionServiceException!
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.getFaultParamElements(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2925)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.getFaultElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2844)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.generateMethodElement(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.loadOperations(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:2242)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.createDOMDocumentForCallbackHandler(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1232)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.writeCallBackHandlers(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:1198)
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:500)
... 63 more
```

what is going wrong?

On some forums people discussed this matter and said it could be resolved by adding

```
<wsdl:fault>
```

in wsdl but in my case fault is already present in wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your bindings

```
<wsdl:fault name="fault">
  <soap:fault use="literal" name="fault" />
</wsdl:fault>
```

Just make sure that name of the fault is changed to whatever is your custom fault name is

Comment: eclipse add this tag in the wsdl automatically, doesn't work.